# Validação de campos em java

Tags: java, validação

Galera como faço uma verificação em java SE para algum dado, para retornar uma mensagem e pedir novamente esta informação caso esteja incorreta, de forma elegante seguindo as boas práticas de orientação a objetos?

Comment: Creio que essa pergunta seja **principalmente baseada em opiniões** e perguntas desse tipo não são aceitas aqui. Você pode editar sua questão se tiver uma dúvida mais concreta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se pode ajudar:

```
if (txtNome.getText().isEmpty()) {
     exibeMensagem();
     txtNome.requestFocus();
     return;
}
```

Caso não ajude, melhore um pouco sua pergunta e especifique melhor o seu problema, como o @Jéferson Bueno sugeriu.